# Various errors using VisionServiceClient in XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I am trying to create a simple Xamarin forms app which allows the user to browse for or take a photo and have azure cognitive services tag the photo using a custom vision model.

I am unable to get the client to successfully authenticate or find a resource per the error message in the exception produced by the VisionServiceClient. Am I missing something? What would be the correct values to use for the arguments to VisionServiceClient?

*All keys have been removed from the below images, they are populated.*

Exception thrown in VS2017:

> 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.ClientException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Call to VisionServiceClient:

```
private const string endpoint = @"https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/prediction/v1.0";
private const string key = "";

VisionServiceClient visionClient = new VisionServiceClient(key, endpoint);
VisualFeature[] features = { VisualFeature.Tags, VisualFeature.Categories, VisualFeature.Description };
try
{
     AnalysisResult temp = await visionClient.AnalyzeImageAsync(imageStream,                    
     features.ToList(), null);

     return temp;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     return null;
}
```

VS Exception Error:

[image: Exception thrown by visionClient.AnalyzeImageAsync()]

Azure Portal for cognitive services:

[image: Cognitive Services Overview]

[image: Cognitive Services Keys]

Custom Vision Portal:

[image: Custom Vision Portal Settings Page]

[image: Project Prediction URL Popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing the *Computer* Vision and the *Custom* Vision APIs.  You are attempting to use the client SDK for the former using the API key of the latter.

For .NET languages, you'll want the [Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Prediction](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Prediction) NuGet package.

Your code will end up looking something like this:

```
ICustomVisionPredictionClient client = new CustomVisionPredictionClient()
{
    ApiKey = PredictionKey,
    Endpoint = "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
};
ImagePrediction prediction = await client.PredictImageAsync(ProjectId, stream, IterationId);
```

Comment: You are correct cthrash, where do you get the Guid for the project id? You can get it as a string off the portal so do I just do a Guid.Parse to pass the I'd to PredictImageAsync?

Comment: On the same Project Settings page where you see your Prediction Key, you should also see a Project Id.  The SDK expects a string, no need to parse.

Comment: The call to PredictImageAsync expects a Guid type as the first parameter for project id not a string, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: My mistake - you are correct, you'll need to `new Guid('...')` or use of the `Parse` methods.

Comment: When I try that I now get an http error for the rest request. The message is "Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'"

Comment: Do you see an iteration name 'Workspace' on your project page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187514/discussion-between-cthrash-and-schwagmister).

Comment: Updated the answer - you'll want to supply the Iteration ID (a GUID) unless you've set a default one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to cthrash for the extended help and talking with me in chat. Using his post along with a little troubleshooting I have figured out what works for me. The code is super clunky but it was just to test and make sure I'm able to do this. To answer the question:

**Nuget packages and classes**

Using cthrash's post I was able to get both the training and prediction nuget packages installed, which are the correct packages for this particular application. I needed the following classes:

> `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Prediction`
>   `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Prediction.Models`
>   `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training`
>   `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Training.Models`

**Endpoint Root**

Following some of the steps [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/csharp-tutorial-od) I determined that the endpoint URL's only need to be the root, not the full URL provided in the Custom Vision Portal. For instance,

> https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Prediction/

Was changed to

> https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

I used both the key and endpoint from the Custom Vision Portal and making that change I was able to use both a training and prediction client to pull the projects and iterations.

**Getting Project Id**

In order to use `CustomVisionPredictionClient.PredictImageAsync` you need a `Guid` for the project id and an iteration id if a default iteration is not set in the portal.

I tested two ways to get the project id,

**Using project id string from portal**

1. Grab the project id string from the portal under the project settings.
2. For the first argument to `PredictImageAsync` pass

   > `Guid.Parse(projectId)`

**Using the training client**

1. Create a new `CustomVisionTrainingClient`
2. To get a list of `<Project>` use

   > `TrainingClient.GetProjects().ToList()`
3. In my case I only had a single project so I would just need the first element.

   > `Guid projectId = projects[0].Id`

**Getting Iteration Id**

To get the iteration id of a project you need the `CustomVisionTrainingClient`.

1. Create the client
2. To get a list of `<Iteration>` use

   > `client.GetIterations(projectId).ToList()`
3. In my case I had only a single iteration so I just need the first element.

   > `Guid iterationId = iterations[0].Id`

I am now able to use my model to classify images. In the code below, fileStream is the image stream passed to the model.

```
public async Task<string> Predict(Stream fileStream)
{
    string projectId = "";
    //string trainingEndpoint = "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.2/Training/";
    string trainingEndpoint = "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/";
    string trainingKey = "";
    //string predictionEndpoint = "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Prediction/";
    string predictionEndpoint = "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";
    string predictionKey = "";

    CustomVisionTrainingClient trainingClient = new CustomVisionTrainingClient
    {
        ApiKey = trainingKey,
        Endpoint = trainingEndpoint
    };

    List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();

    try
    {
        projects = trainingClient.GetProjects().ToList();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get projects:\n\n" + ex.Message);
        return "Unable to obtain projects.";
    }

    Guid ProjectId = Guid.Empty;

    if(projects.Count > 0)
    {
        ProjectId = projects[0].Id;
    }

    if (ProjectId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to obtain project ID");
        return "Unable to obtain project id.";
    }

    List<Iteration> iterations = new List<Iteration>();

    try
    {
        iterations = trainingClient.GetIterations(ProjectId).ToList();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to obtain iterations.");
        return "Unable to obtain iterations.";
    }

    foreach(Iteration itr in iterations)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(itr.Name + "\t" + itr.Id + "\n");
    }

    Guid iteration = Guid.Empty;

    if(iterations.Count > 0)
    {
        iteration = iterations[0].Id;
    }

    if(iteration == Guid.Empty)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to obtain project iteration.");
        return "Unable to obtain project iteration";
    }

    CustomVisionPredictionClient predictionClient = new CustomVisionPredictionClient
    {
        ApiKey = predictionKey,
        Endpoint = predictionEndpoint
    };

    var result = await predictionClient.PredictImageAsync(Guid.Parse(projectId), fileStream, iteration);

    string resultStr = string.Empty;

    foreach(PredictionModel pred in result.Predictions)
    {
        if(pred.Probability >= 0.85)
            resultStr += pred.TagName + " ";
    }

    return resultStr;
}
```

Comment: I also discovered that the newest iteration is always the first element of the iteration list. So using list[0] or list.first() would always get the newest iteration.